# ImportRange Not Working Properly - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data for range A1:J from the sheet named "BODY COVER STOCK" using ImportRange function the first Column shows NA and Column H,I,J shows blank under headings. Can anyone help me out in finding where I am going wrong with this.

Data SpreadSheet link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzSslzdKFtbxEdPQPX5Ox0Cq2NNaqRViYX3ookQ4I1w/edit#gid=0

Target SpreadSheet Link -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18zkwzlPi1PREKW8EG71NGGokOULKRMqAdEck-u3YvHA/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance.

Formulae I am using -

`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HzSslzdKFtbxEdPQPX5Ox0Cq2NNaqRViYX3ookQ4I1w/edit#gid=0","BODY COVER STOCK!A1:J")`

Data Sheet Image -
[image: Data Sheet]

Target Sheet Image -
[image: Target Sheet]

Comment: you can remove the apps-script tag since none seems involved. Thank you.

Comment: most likely it's because it takes time in the data sheet to load the first column of values (when I refresh the data sheet, the values are also N/A, then the VLOOKUP puts the correct values)

Comment: @ValLeNain Yea I just noticed, removed the app script tag. But importrange still is not working properly, any idea what should I do. Please help.

Comment: Please upvote and share so that someone can help me out, would really appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** (NOT as IMAGE/Spreadsheet LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a minimal example.[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Is the data in A:A manually input?

Comment: Hi, No the data is not manually inputed, I have used a vlookup and array formuale. But even if I try to Import range B1:J the data in Column H,I,J is blank under headings.. I have never faced such an issue, I cant seem to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

could ba a result of excessive usage of dependency...

if you have editing access to `Data SpreadSheet` try adding an intermediate (new) sheet with this in A1:

```
={BODY COVER STOCK!A1:J}
```

and then import that new sheet with `IMPORTRANGE`

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1HzSslzdKFtbxEdPQPX5Ox0Cq2NNaqRViYX3ookQ4I1w", "new sheet!A1:J")
```

Comment: Hello @player0, I tried creating a DATA SHEET in the same spreadsheet in which data exists, but still facing with the same issue. Also, wouldn't this just increase further dependency, just a question... This is just so confusing have never ever faced such an issue.